# Can't upgrade my Ubuntu form 20.10 to 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: apt, dependencies, 20.10

I can't update my Ubuntu due to this problem: "The requited dependency 'apt(>)2.1.10ubuntu0.3)' is not installed."
I tried to install it but I can not do anything.
Please help.

Comment: There was only one fully supported upgrade path from 20.10; to the next release being Ubuntu 21.04, which closed when 21.04 went EOL.  Jammy upgrade instructions can be read here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades but you'll note no mention of 20.10. Ubuntu allows upgrade from one LTS to the next (20.04 to 22.04), or from one release to the next (20.04->20.10->21.04->21.10->22.04).  A re-install is the usual means where you've ignore the upgrade for so long (non-destructive re-installs are pretty easy for desktop installs).